# largest possible number of elements of S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I could only find 14 after a couple of operations on A and B. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I've seen this lately.  In any case... make sure you remember to include $\emptyset$ and $M$ as well.  You will effectively have the four atomic nonempty subsets: $A\setminus B, A\cap B, B\setminus A$ and $M\setminus (A\cup B)$.  Every element of $S$ can be written as a union of some combination of these four atomic subsets.  There are $2^4$ possible such combinations.

Comment: Hi thanks for the hints! I didn't have A\B or B\A. Can they be generated by the operations specified anyway?

Comment: $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c = A\cap (M\setminus B)$.  The operations given make it so that $S$ is an [algebra of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets).  Note that you can also arrive at $\emptyset$ as $A\cap (M\setminus A)$ and then with $M$ as $M\setminus (A\cap (M\setminus A))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $S$ is an [algebra of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets).

There are effectively up to four "atomic" subsets here, namely $A\setminus B, A\cap B, B\setminus A$ and $M\setminus (A\cup B)$, corresponding to the four regions on a [venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) for two sets.

It follows that any combination of unions of these atomic subsets will be an element of $S$ and vice versa (including the empty union, corresponding to the empty set) and so there are $2^4=16$ such combinations, seen by applying standard counting principles.

I say "up to four" because it is possible that some of these atomic subsets are the same or are empty, for example as happens when $A$ is a subset of $B$ or when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

---

A similar argument shows that had we started with $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ there would be up to $2^{2^n}$ elements in $S$ and that the number of elements in $S$ is always a power of $2$.